# Empty response of SOAP request

Tags: delphi, soap

I have two delphi clients of one ASMX service. One client is normal desktop application and other is Outlook add-in.
Everything works fine (SOAP calls to ASMX service) on my PC. But on one of my costumers have problems with SOAP calls within Outlook add-in, and at the same time desktop application works as expected on the same machine.

The problem with SOAP call within Outlook add-in is error "XML document must have a top level element". Reason of this error is empty response of call. Take a look at logs:

```
8/7/2013-1:12:29 PM  Response: 
8/7/2013-1:12:29 PM  XML document must have a top level element.

Line: 0

                 XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.LoadData + $2AA
                 XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.SetActive + $A8
                 XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.LoadFromStream + $29
                 Rio.TRIO.Generic + $70F
```

Response stream is retrieved in HttpRio AfterExecute method using call

```
fResponse.LoadFromStream(Response);
```

The question is: what is the reason of this error, how can one client on the same machine work fine and other not? what can I do to reproduce, diagnose this situation?

P.S. I know that it would be great to have sniffed http packets, but I don't have access to the costumer's PC to run http sniffer.

Comment: Can you log the SOAP requests from both apps and compare/show these? Bad requests can result in empty responses, depending on the server. Is it a custom server, or something we all know like e.g. Exchange Web Services? (In that case, please edit your question.)

Comment: This is custom C# service. Logging request is my second thought. I've added this to client and will send to costumer. Will update question with more information after response from costumer.

Comment: Does the Outlook add-in run with exactly the same user privileges?

Comment: Interesting question. I think yes. How can user privileges influence soap request?

Comment: re: user privileges: If the soap request attaches a cert for authentication, the privileges must allow access to the cert in order to attach it.  And also the private key file.  In our environment, failure to attach a cert results in a "policy falsified" being returned by an enterprise firewall-like appliance.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Your log doesn't show the timestamp of the original request.  If the time difference happens to fall on a 30 or 60 second boundary, then this is almost certainly a timeout situation.  i.e. no response was ever received. If it happens right away, then your request likely is not getting out, and is being blocked by a firewall.